# error de java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18"

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo txt en un jframe y me sale el siguiente error:

> ejava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18"

el frame son cuatro columnas

```
private Object[][] leerusuarios()   {
    Object[][] data;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("usuarios.txt"));
        String linea= br.readLine();
        int numFilas=Integer.parseInt(linea);
        data= new Object [numFilas][4];
        for(int i=0;i<numFilas;i++){
            linea=br.readLine();
            String[] datosUsuario=linea.split(";");
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                data [i][j]=datosUsuario[j];
                System.out.println(br.readLine());

                br.close();
```

...

```
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        data= new Object[0][4];
    }
    return data;
}
```

Archivo usuarios.txt:

```
andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18 juan;hernandes;juan@poligran.edu.co;20 maria;castro;maria@poligran.edu.co;30 david;peña;david@poligran.edu.co;26
```

Comment: podrías explicar en la pregunta el error que te esta saliendo. Gracias

Comment: estoy tratando de leer un archivo txt en un jframe y me sale  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18" el frame son cuatro columnas

Comment: agrega a tu pregunta lo que acabas de colocar en el comentario. Gracias

Comment: subí tu archivo usuarios.txt también

Comment: el archivo es el siguiente

Comment: andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18
juan;hernandes;juan@poligran.edu.co;20
maria;castro;maria@poligran.edu.co;30
david;peña;david@poligran.edu.co;26

Comment: el método leerusuarios esta incompleto. Podrías agregar todo. gracias

Comment: } catch (IOException ex) {
   
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   data= new Object[0][4];
  }
 return data;
}

Comment: @oscar: Por favor edita tu pregunta para incorporar la información adicional en vez de ir agregando comentarios con código. Dejar que otros lo hagan por ti corre el riesgo que no sea en realidad lo que tienes y puede que las respuestas no se basen en tu realidad.

Comment: @oscar agregué el código a tu pregunta. En vez de ponerlo en comentarios, encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta. Además, por favor, intenta indentar el código. De hecho, creo que eso es lo único que hace falta para que sean evidentes algunos de los errores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código corregido es. Estaba mal como estaba implementado.

```
private Object[][] leerusuarios()   {
    Object[][] data;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("usuarios.txt"));
        String linea = br.readLine();
        String[] filas = linea.split(" ");
        int numFilas = filas.length;
        data = new Object [numFilas][4];
        for(int i = 0; i < numFilas; i++){
            linea = br.readLine();
            String[] datosUsuario = filas[i].split(";");
            for(int j = 0; j < datosUsuario.length; j++){
                data[i][j] = datosUsuario[j];
                System.out.println(data[i][j]);
            }
        }
        // Se cierra porque ya no se usa mas.
        br.close();
    }catch (IOException ex) { 
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
         data = new Object[0][4]; 
    } 
    return data;
}
```

Comment: tienes razon ya lo probe me llena la primera fila

Comment: si soluciona tu pregunta podrías marcar como solucionado. Gracias

Comment: gracias ya lo soluciono es usted el mejor

Comment: Te recomiendo de verificar que esto realmente hace lo que debería. Al final no se sabe realmente lo que quieres, pero este código va a concluir que hay una sola fila y solo va a leer y procesar la línea `juan;hernandes;juan@poligran.edu.co;20`. Lo demás de tu archivo lo va a ignorar. ¿Es eso realmente lo que quieres?

Answer (score 0):

No has explicado los detalles de cómo se supone que debe funcionar el programa con el archivo. Pero según la porción siguiente:

```
BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(new FileReader("usuarios.txt"));
String linea= br.readLine();
int numFilas=Integer.parseInt(linea);
```

... parece que la idea es que la primera línea de tu archivo debería contener un valor numérico que representa el número de filas y que luego usas para determinar cuántas líneas más debes leer y procesar del archivo.

Pero en tu caso, la primera línea contiene el valor:

> andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18

... que obviamente no se puede convertir a un entero, de allí tu error.

Me parece que lo único que necesitas es agregarle una línea inicial a tu archivo con el número de filas.

Ejemplo:

> 4
>   andres;rodrigues;andres@poligran.edu.co;18
>   juan;hernandes;juan@poligran.edu.co;20
>   maria;castro;maria@poligran.edu.co;30
>   david;peña;david@poligran.edu.co;26